# Is it possible to find a solution for an unknown the group of integers mod p?

Tags: group-theory, modular-arithmetic

I have two equations, using elements in the group of integers mod p

```
a=g^k*m
```

and

```
m=a*g^-k
```

I am taking `g^-k=(g^-1)^k` where `g^-1` is the modular inverse.

Given that I know all of the integer values for g, g^-1, and k, can I solve for m?

Edit: I have just read that solving for an element, when the element appears more than once is not possible in the general case. Are there any cases where this is possible?

Comment: I don't follow. The second one is just the first one where one has already solved for $m$, so I don't see what the question is.

Comment: Sorry - I guess what I am saying is that if I have concrete, not symbolic values, of g, and k, can I solve for m, since if I substitute, I would get `m=g^k*m*(g^-1)^k` but according to this page, https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Manipulating_equations_in_groups, I don't think it is possible, since m appears twice in the equation

Comment: But it does not appear twice in the second one.

Comment: I took that to mean that it is appearing on both sides of the equation. According to that webpage I linked, if an element is on both sides of the equation, it can't be solved for that element.